# Using SweetAlert2 to replace "return confirm()" on an ASP.Net Button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sweetalert, sweetalert2

When working in ASP.Net, I often like to have "Are you sure?" popups when clicking things like a delete button. This is easily done like so:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnDelete" Text="Delete" onClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" onClick="btnDelete_Click" />
```

I really like the styling and general feel of SweetAlert2's confirm dialog, however they're seemingly a bit more troublesome when I'm attempting to integrate them in a similar fashion. Can someone explain to me how I might be able to return the SweetAlert2 dialog result to either continue or stop based on the button clicked?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnDelete" Text="Delete" onClientClick="return sweetAlertConfirm();" onClick="btnDelete_Click" />
```

```
    function sweetAlertConfirm() {
        event.preventDefault();
        swal({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
//      }).then(function() {
//          CONFIRM WAS CHOSEN
//      }, {function() {
//          CANCEL WAS CHOSEN
        });
    }
```

The dialog comes up and the delete is not processed, of course, as I'm currently doing an `event.preventDefault()` and nothing is being returned. I'm also noticing that [I can use promises](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/), adding a `.then()` after my `swal({...})`, however I'm not sure how that would be used in this instance.

If need be I can get tricky with a hidden button that actually triggers the code-behind method, and click that hidden button based on the user selection, but I'm hoping to avoid this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the SweetAlert2 dialog is processed asynchronously, you have to trigger another button click programmatically when the promise is resolved. Instead of creating a hidden button, you can reuse `btnDelete` by setting a flag to indicate that the action was already confirmed. That flag will be detected when the second click is processed, and the button click will be allowed to proceed and to trigger the server event.

```
<asp:Button ... OnClientClick="return sweetAlertConfirm(this);" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />
```

```
function sweetAlertConfirm(btnDelete) {
    if (btnDelete.dataset.confirmed) {
        // The action was already confirmed by the user, proceed with server event
        btnDelete.dataset.confirmed = false;
        return true;
    } else {
        // Ask the user to confirm/cancel the action
        event.preventDefault();
        swal({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        })
        .then(function () {
            // Set data-confirmed attribute to indicate that the action was confirmed
            btnDelete.dataset.confirmed = true;
            // Trigger button click programmatically
            btnDelete.click();
        }).catch(function (reason) {
            // The action was canceled by the user
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var obj = { status: false, ele: null };
function DeleteConfirm(btnDelete) {

    if (obj.status) {
        obj.status = false;
        return true;
    };

    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        type: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.value) {
            obj.status = true;
            //do postback on success
            obj.ele.click();

            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Deleted!',
                text: 'Your file has been deleted.',
                type: 'success',
                timer: 800
            })
        }
    });
    obj.ele = btnDelete;
    return false;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8/dist/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@8/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>

<asp:LinkButton ID="cmdDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" OnClientClick="return DeleteConfirm(this);">
```