# I can't use sweetalert to make a confirmation in ASP using linkbutton

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, sweetalert

I'm working on a school project and I can't do the deleting confirmation using sweetalert.

This is the script:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
                        function myDelete {
              e.preventDefault();
            swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "You want to Save this project?",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes, I am sure!',
                cancelButtonText: "No, cancel it!",
                closeOnConfirm: true,
                closeOnCancel: true
            },
            function (isConfirm) {
                if (isConfirm) {
                    return true; 
                    
                   // $(this).trigger('click');
                    $('#LinkButton1').click();
                   // e.currentTarget.submit();
                } else {
                      return false; 
                    // alert("False");
                }
            });
                            </script>
```

And what i want to do is when i click on the linkbutton on my gridview it shows the sweetalert confirmation asking if i want to delete or no!

This is my linkbutton:

```html
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CssClass="delete" runat="server" OnClientClick="return Confirm(this, event);" CommandName="Delete">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

Please, i really need help with this!
Thanks.

Comment: Oddly enough, I've actually asked this exact question before!  [Using SweetAlert2 to replace "return confirm()" on an ASP.Net Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729434/using-sweetalert2-to-replace-return-confirm-on-an-asp-net-button) :)

Answer (score 0):

Your asp link button will call the confirm function. Confirm will return true if 'Yes, I am sure!' is pressed

Using sweetalert@2.1.2

```
function confirm(button, e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var buttonId = $(button).attr('id');
    console.log(buttonId);
    swal({
      title: "Are you sure?",
      text: "You want to Save this project?",
      type: "warning",
      buttons: ["No, cancel it!", "Yes, I am sure!"],
    }).then((confirm) => {
      if (confirm) {
        console.log("confirm:", confirm);
        return true;
      } else {
        console.log("confirm:", confirm);
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/167a4z8k/3/

Comment: I tried this but it instantly deletes without asking for confirmation